# How can you compare a day average value to all values on that day?

Tags: python, csv, indexing, extract, average

I have created two dataframes in Python: one with an average heart rate frequency per day, and another dataframe with the heart rate frequency during multiple moments on each day. I now want to compare these heart rate frequencies throughout the day with the average heart rate frequency per day, but I do not know how to do this.
The problem is that I can not find out how to connect the average of the day to all values throughout that day, and that automatically the average for the next day is compared to all values from the next day, since the "Length of values does not match length of index".

Comment: Can you please provide part of your data frames, your code and - if possible - the error message as well as your desired output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ko3 sure, the code for the average heart rate per day is: 

`df_sleep.insert(df_sleep.shape[1], "heartRateAvg", [0]*len(df_sleep), True)

for day in range(0, len(df_sleep)):
    heartbeat_list = []
    for hb_measurement in range(0, len(df_HR)):
        if (df_HR['unixTime'][hb_measurement] > df_sleep['startUnix'][day] and df_HR['unixTime'][hb_measurement] < df_sleep['stopUnix'][day]):
            heartbeat_list.append(df_HR['heartRate'][hb_measurement])
    if len(heartbeat_list) > 0:
        df_sleep.at[day, 'heartRateAvg'] = mean(heartbeat_list)

df_sleep`

Comment: From this code I get a resulting data frame where I get the average heart rate frequency per day. Then I have another data frame with the heart rate frequency measured on multiple moments throughout each day, and I want to take the ratio of the heart rate during each moment to the average heart rate of that day.

When I want to compare them now, it simply compares the first row of the first data frame with the first row of the second data frame and so on, but I want to group the data from multiple moments throughout a day per day.

Comment: So I want the index of the data frame from all the data measured during multiple moments throughout a day to be set as an example to number 1. Then all the data from that day is listed in the next columns, and the same goes for day 2. I do not want to get a mean or something, I just want all the data from each day to be connected to one index number